# Receiving Unicode strings with Indy 10

Tags: delphi, unicode, indy, indy10, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using the latest Delphi 10.4.2 with Indy 10.

In a REST server, JSON commands are received and handled. It works fine except for Unicode.

A simple JSON like this:

```json
{"driverNote": "Test"}
```

is shown correctly

[image]

If I now change to Unicode Russian characters:

```json
{"driverNote": "Статья"}
```

[image]

Not sure where I should begin to track this. I expect `ARequestInfo.FormParams` to have the same value in debugger as `s` variable.

If I debug Indy itself, `FormParams` are set in this code:

```
if LRequestInfo.PostStream <> nil then
begin
  // decoding percent-encoded octets and applying the CharSet is handled by
  // DecodeAndSetParams() further below...
  EnsureEncoding(LEncoding, enc8Bit);
  LRequestInfo.FormParams := 
    ReadStringFromStream( LRequestInfo.PostStream, 
                          -1, 
                          LEncoding
                          {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}, LEncoding{$ENDIF});
  DoneWithPostStream(AContext, LRequestInfo); // don't need the PostStream anymore
end;
```

It use `enc8Bit`. But my string has 16-bits characters.

Is this handled incorrect in Indy?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you quoted from `IdCustomHTTPServer.pas` is not what is in Indy's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/).

In the official code, `TIdHTTPServer` does not decode the `PostStream` to `FormParams` unless the `ContentType` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

```pascal
if LRequestInfo.PostStream <> nil then begin
  if TextIsSame(LContentType, ContentTypeFormUrlencoded) then
  begin
    // decoding percent-encoded octets and applying the CharSet is handled by DecodeAndSetParams() further below...
    EnsureEncoding(LEncoding, enc8Bit);
    LRequestInfo.FormParams := ReadStringFromStream(LRequestInfo.PostStream, -1, LEncoding{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}, LEncoding{$ENDIF});
    DoneWithPostStream(AContext, LRequestInfo); // don't need the PostStream anymore
  end;
end;
```

That `ContentType` check was added way back in 2010, so I don't know why it is not present in your version.

In your example, the `ContentType` is `'application/json'`, so the raw JSON *should* be in the `PostStream` and the `FormParams` *should* be blank.

That being said, in your version of Indy, `TIdHTTPServer` is simply reading the raw bytes from the `PostStream` and zero-extending each byte to a 16-bit character in the `FormParams`. To recover the original bytes, simply truncate each `Char` to an 8-bit `Byte`. For instance, you can use Indy's `ToBytes()` function in the `IdGlobal` unit, specifying `enc8Bit`/`IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` as the byte encoding.

JSON is most commonly transmitted as UTF-8 (and that is the case in your example), so when you have access to the raw bytes, in any version, make sure you parse the JSON bytes as UTF-8.

Comment: Ok you are correct. Our version is patched and json is assigned in contenttype